# how to pagination razor page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

i have a table for saving some ids for send request to web service and save my data to view model and show data in view page with IEnumerable viewmodel.Now i want to have a pagination at the end of my page because i have more than 100 product in my archive page.Now how can i have Pagination for this page??

//CONTROLLER

```
            public ActionResult Archive()
           {
        var selectspecial = db.ProviderSelections.Where(a => 
         a.SpecialSuggestion == true && a.IsActive == 
          true).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateDate).Select(a => 
           a.ID).ToList();
        var lastitem = selectspecial.Last();
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectspecial.Count; i++)
        {
            var selectid = selectspecial[i];
            lst.Add(selectid.ToString());
        }
        StringBuilder itemlist = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            itemlist.Append(item).Append(",");
        }
        string id = itemlist.ToString() + lastitem;

        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = 
        "application/json;charset=utf-8";
        string url = "MYWEBSERVICEURL?pids=" + id;
        webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("USERNAME:PASSWORD"));
        webclient.Headers.Add("Request-type", "REQUESTTYPE");

        string result = webclient.DownloadString(url);

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(result);
        JToken jUser = jObject["X"];
        List<BriefDetailsViewModel> briefdetails = new 
        List<BriefDetailsViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in jUser)
        {
            BriefDetailsViewModel brief = new BriefDetailsViewModel();

            brief.address = (string)item["address"];
           //OTHER LINES ARE LIKE ABOVE LINE




            briefdetails.Add(brief);
        }

        return View(briefdetails);
    }
```

//Archive.cshtml

```
        @model IEnumerable<ROOT.BriefDetailsViewModel>  


        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
        {                   
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">

                        <div class="text TextBox">
                            @item.description 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                  //More Data like this....
        }


          //PAGINATION BOX



        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice by adding pagination feature to your web service to be like this :

```
string url = "MYWEBSERVICEURL?pids=" + id + "&pageId="+pageId;
```

Also use page size variable, then you can page your data using LINQ :

example :

```
int numberOfObjectsPerPage = 10;
var queryResultPage = dataContext.Employees.OrderBy(a=>a.ID)
  .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber)
  .Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage).ToList();
```

If you cannot update your web service, or you are using external web service you can read the data then page it before return your view :

```
briefdetails = briefdetails
.Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber)
.Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
return View(briefdetails);
```

Also in your html you can render something for paging below your table :
          //You called it PAGINATION BOX

```
for(int i=1,i<pageNumber;i++)
{
<a href="@Url.Action("YOUR_ACTION",new {pageId = i})">@i<a/>
}
```